# How do i add a page to a wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

I need to add a page to a wordpress site. However, for legal reasons, the page cannot be placed in/managed by wordpress as we are not allowed to make any changes to the page or it's content. How can I add this page to our site, but keep it outside wordpress management.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It sounds like you could just upload a `.html` file into the folder, but I'd be pretty baffled that such a solution would work if you're legally not permitted to use the WordPress admin to add content.

Comment: Maybe you can use the [iframe plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/) ? If you need to host the page elsewhere and a simple link won't do.

Comment: I've tried just adding the files, to both the web root and to the wp-content folder, but continue to get 404 errors. Since it's static, I wanted to avoid a plugin and was hoping to just be able to link to it, like @ceejayoz suggested, but just cannot get it seen. Is my .htaccess preventing this?

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1):

Odd request, but here's one idea:

Create a page template with no dynamic content from the post, load this content into it. The only way to edit the file would be through raw code. Anything entered into the post/page content area would not appear.